# PHPExcel loading large file

Tags: php, performance, phpexcel

I need to get sheet names and first row of every sheet from xls/xlsx/ods file. To avoid manual file type detection I'm using following code to load:

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath);
```

My *.ods file is about 5MB big and this function takes too long to execute. I need it in a real time, let's say ~5 seconds is accaptable. Is there any solution to read just this information without waiting so much time? I'm using PHPExcel 1.7.6, but I would appreciate any solution with any other 3rd party library. Just to be clear, my use case is to show file structure to  user right after uploading the file, so he can accept it for further import.

Comment: Perhaps upgrading to a more recent version of PHPExcel would help; version 1.7.6 is slower than more recent versions - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/Version-Performance-Statistics

Comment: But what do you mean by showing the "file structure", PHPExcel allows you to extract some information from a spreadsheet file without loading the entire file, and there are methods to speed up loading a file if you don't need every detail of its contents (e.g. `readDataOnly(true)`

Comment: Thanks, nice performance comparison, but the newest version helped only a little bit. I also tried ''setReadDataOnly()'' and it is only small improvement too. Showing the "file structure" I mean sheet names and first row in each worksheet as a table header, so no other data at all. But it looks like the problem is really only this ''load'' function, reading rows itself doesn't take to long.

Comment: Then you'll need to use a read filter if you want to speed things up any further by only reading the first line; or find an alternative library that can handle all those file formats - you might have better luck using [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) with MS Excel or [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) with Open/Libre Office

Comment: I solved it using this library: https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader, it has much less functionality than phpexcel, but for basic reading it's just enough